# Create <a> tags around divs using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using Jquery to create multiple products within a page using the below code..

```
    $("#product-container").empty()
    slicedata.forEach(function(e,i,a){
        var obj = e;
        i = parseInt(obj.id)
        $("<a href = /product >").appendTo('#product-container')
        $("<div id = productid" + i + " class = product-cards </div>").appendTo('#product-container')
        $("<div id='product" + i + "left'  class='product-cards-left' style='background-image:url(  " + imagepath_start + obj.image_caption + ")'> </div>").appendTo('#productid' + i);
        $("<div id = product" + i + "right class = product-cards-right> </div>").appendTo('#productid' + i   )
        $("<label><b>  Price: <b></label>  <label>" + '$' + obj.price + "</label><br>").appendTo('#product' + i +"right"   )
        $("<label><b>  Old Price: <b></label>  <label>" + '$' + obj.old_price + "</label><br>").appendTo('#product' + i +"right"   )
        $("<label><b>  Author Name: <b></label>  <label>" + obj.author_name + "</label>").appendTo('#product' + i +"right"   )
        $("<div id= elementid style='display:none' >"+ obj.id+" </div>").appendTo('#product' + i +"right"   )
    })
```

Now,I need to add an `<a>` tag around the divs, so that when the user clicks the product card he will be taken to the details page...

I'm using the `<a>` tag to build around each product using the below stmt but it creates the `<a>` and closes it immediately..I need to close the `<a>` after all the divs(ie; products are created).

```
    $("<a href = /product >").appendTo('#product-container')
```

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: I added this stmt..$("<a href='/product' />").wrap("<div id = productid" + i + " class = product-cards </div>").......but it does not work

Comment: not hard to simply throw the strings in and wrap it manually as it's created. Making far too many `append`'s as it is

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$.wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) for this.

```
$("<div id='productid" + i + "' class='product-cards'></div>")
.appendTo('#product-container')
.wrap("<a href='/product'></a>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Kfj3/1/

Comment: I tried using this fiddle but looks like it does not work----http://jsfiddle.net/3Kfj3/

Comment: You'll have to wrap last it turns out